# Flex - Using Flash button component

Tags: flash, apache-flex, swc

I made a movieclip tab style navigator with 3 tabs, HTML, PHP, JAVASCRIPT. Each tab has a group of buttons that inserts a string into a TextInput. What I want to do is export it as a swc, import it into Flash Builder. Is it possible to do this and maintain the buuttons' functionality?

I guess put simply, can a component have a working button?

Comment: Yes, you can. The adobe components beginner guide would have answered that by the way.

Comment: Oh thanks. Didn't know about that, or I wouldn't have asked.

Comment: Is there something specific I can search for?

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/flash/components.html